# Why does parametrized type instance works without specifying type parameter

Tags: haskell, typeclass, type-parameter

When having a parametrized type:
`data A a=X a| Y`

I have tried (successfully) implementing `Functor` and `Applicative` without specifiying the type parameter:

`instance Functor A where` instead of `instance Functor (A a) where`.
Why does it work ? 
Looking in [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses) it seems all examples specify the type parameter in all their `typeclass instances`.
When should you neglect the type parameter ?

Comment: The type signature of `fmap` (in `Functor` is `fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`, so here we apply `a` to the type constructor `A`, given that we would make `A Int` a functor, how should we hande `f a` (so `A Int a`)?

Comment: The type parameter is thus not "neglected", Here `f` is basically a function that takes a type and constructs a new type.

Comment: When using `instance Functor A where` its like we partially apply `A` ? and we supply the type when we call `fmap` ? (Not sure if i understood)

Comment: @BercoviciAdrain: exactly, `f` is a "function" that transforms a type (like `Int`) into a type `A Int`.

Comment: But then it means that if we specify in the instance `A [something]` and we call `fmap A [something_else]` it crashes . Does it mean that in the instance implementation we can `fill` any `type` parameter or let it free: Ex:  `instance T a b c where` , `instance T Int b c ` ,`instance T Int b Int `..etc?

Comment: we just pass a function that constructs a type. The type class itself can then "construct types". For example it could have done something like `otherfmap :: (Int -> String) -> f Int -> f String`, so the parameter is not per se free, but for `Functor`, yes it is free.

Comment: By function you mean the type constructor ?

Comment: yes, but well a type constructor is a function on the "type level", just like a data constructor is a function on the "instance level".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> `instance Functor A where` instead of `instance Functor (A a) where`.
>   Why does it work ?

I find this easier to understand using GHC's kinding system. Let's start from a simple case, and experiment in GHCi:

```
> :k Eq Int
Eq Int :: Constraint
```

This tells us that `Eq Int` is a constraint, some property that might be verified during type checking. Indeed, if we type check `(12 :: Int) == (42 :: Int)`, the compiler will verify that integers can be compared, resolving the constraint `Eq Int`.

What is `Eq` alone, the name of the class without the `Int` parameter?

```
> :k Eq
Eq :: * -> Constraint
```

This tells us that `Eq` can be thought of a function from types (`*` is the kind of types) to constraint.

Indeed, in `Eq Int`, `Int` is a type, so we have `Int :: *` making `Int` a well-kinded argument to pass to `Eq`.

Enough of type classes, what about type constructors?

```
> :k Maybe Int
Maybe Int :: *
```

No surprise, `Maybe Int` is a type

```
> :k Maybe
Maybe :: * -> *
```

`Maybe` instead, is a function from types to types (`*->*`). This is indeed what the `Maybe` type constructor does: mapping a type (`Int`) to a type (`Maybe Int`).

Back to the original question. Why can't we write `instance Functor (A a)` but we can instead write `instance Functor A`? Well, we have that

```
> :k A Int
A Int :: *
> :k A
A :: * -> *
```

and, most importantly,

```
> :k Functor
Functor :: (* -> *) -> Constraint
```

This tells us the the kind of the `Functor` type class is not the same kind of the `Eq` type class. `Eq` expects a type as an argument, while `Functor` expects something of kind `(* -> *)` as an argument. `A` fits that kind, while `A Int` does not.

This happens when, in the definition of the class, the argument is applied to some other type. E.g.

```
class C1 a where
   foo :: a -> Bool
```

results in `C1 :: * -> Constraint`. Instead,

```
class C2 f where
   bar :: f Int -> Bool
```

results in `C2 :: (* -> *) -> Constraint`, since `f` is not itself used as a type, `f Int` is, so `f` must be a parameterized type of kind `* -> *`.

Answer (score 8):

> When should you neglect the type parameter?

The type parameter is not "*neglected*". Let us first take a look at the `Functor` type class:

```
class Functor f where
    fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Notice the `f a` and `f b` in the type signature. We thus here "construct types" for the type signature of `fmap`.

Here `f` is thus basically a function that takes a type and transforms it into a type.  For example if `f ~ A` if `a ~ Int`, then `f a` generates the `A Int` type.

[*Learn You a Haskell for the Greater Good!*](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids#the-newtype-keyword) actually explains this in its chapter about *Functors, Applicatives and Monoids*:

> Many times, we want to make our types instances of certain type
>   classes, but the type parameters just don't match up for what we want
>   to do. It's easy to **make `Maybe` an instance of `Functor`**, because
>   the `Functor` type class is defined like this:
>
> ```
> class Functor f where  
>     fmap :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
> ```
>
> So we just start out with:
>
> ```
>   instance Functor Maybe where
> ```
>
> And then implement `fmap`. All the type parameters add up because the `Maybe` takes the place of `f` in
>   the definition of the `Functor` type class and so if we look at `fmap`
>   like it only worked on `Maybe`, it ends up behaving like:
>
> ```
> fmap :: (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> Maybe b
> ```
>
> (...)